# Vanity URLs with IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm struggling. I'd like a user to be able to go to this url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder/some-id-text
```

and have URL Rewrite direct that request here:

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder/index.aspx?id=some-id-text
```

http://www.mysite.com/folder/some-id-text should be the only url the user ever sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your project edit Global.asax file and add the code below.

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.MapPageRoute("somename",
            "folder/{text-id}",
            "~/index.aspx");
    }
```

then in your index.aspx you can find this variable as

```
 string text_id = RouteData.Values["text-id"].ToString();
```

further ref http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Easy-Steps-to-URL-2f792901

Comment: Thank you! This works great for me. I'm always a little hesitant marking answers correct immediately since everyone hasn't had a chance to chime in, but I'll probably mark it correct tomorrow. Thanks again so much for your help!

Comment: Also, I needed to change "~/index.aspx" to "~/folder/index.aspx".